# Access URL in Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-intl

I have a language reducer that has an initial locale value:

```
const LanguageReducer = function(
  state = { locale: "en", messages: {} },
  action = {}
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_LANGUAGE_SUCCESS:
    ...
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The initial value of locale comes from the current URL. How can I access the URL and locale param in my reducer to initial the locale? I am using React-Router v4

Comment: instead of accessing `url` in reducer, you can pass `locale` as payload where you are dispatching the `action `

Comment: You should keep your reducers pure. I would dispatch an initialization action somewhere when the app starts (let's say for instance when the main component mounts), and pass the URL as the action payload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have (at least) two options, depending on your needs:

1) The simplest method is to dispatch an action from the first page your app loads that uses the `Route props` to pass the url parameter you need to your reducer. See [this page](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router) for a guide. This is the way to go if you can keep your `Route` state and the rest of you application state separate.

2) A more complex method is to use a middleware like [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) to keep your store and React Router synchronised. This will give you a `router` property in your store (containing history, location etc) that you can read from whenever you need to.

Comment: When the component mounts, the web services work based on unset locale. So it's to late to dispatch locale action.

Comment: Is it available in a reducer to initialize the locale? Can I use it in server side rendering?